# Change Index of XTS

Tags: r, xts

I am changing from holding data inside Rstudio to instead keeping it in SQL and importing tables as I need them.

The issue I keep running into is that when I import the table from SQL, I have a data frame that now needs to be converted to XTS, but the index is now an auto integer and not the first column which contains what should be my index.

Is there a way to just specify a new column as the index?

I assume there has to be but I can't find anything.

#### Data

[image: data]

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out rather quickly after posting the question.

```
#Specified the row name as the index using rownames()
rownames(temp_from_sql) <- temp_from_sql$`Date Time`

#deleted the 'Date Time' column
temp <- temp_from_sql[,-1]
```